# Investigating annoying short UI hangs

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring

I just bought a new desktop machine for home (see system details below). It's supposed to be super smooth, but nevertheless I'm experiencing quite frequent UI 'stutters'. It's as in the olden days when your machine was using swap memory and occasionally things just hung for half a second when something had to be swapped in. Same experience here. Typing, video playback, audio playback, everything seems to be affected.

Problem is, this machine is swimming in memory (64GB), has a 4 core Intel CPU at 3.4GHz and it's not running a particle physics simulation in the background. In fact, I'm just running a single Chrome window and it still runs into this issue.

What I'm looking for is a nice and detailed performance monitoring tool where I could literally observe where my threads go during the hang. Does some high priority background process kick in, using up all CPU for a short period? Is it some kind of IO problem? Network issue? Need something more detailed then *top*.

```
|    Linux: Linux version 4.4.0-38-generic (buildd@lgw01-58)                                                                                                                                                       │
│    Build: (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) )                                                                                                                                          │
│    Release  : 4.4.0-38-generic                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│    Version  : #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016                                                                                                                                                         │
│    cpuinfo: model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz                                                                                                                                                 │
│    cpuinfo: vendor_id : GenuineIntel                                                                                                                                                                             │
│    cpuinfo: microcode : 0x74                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│    cpuinfo: cpuid level : 22                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│    # of CPUs: 8                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│    Machine  : x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│    /etc/*ease[1]: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                              │
│    /etc/*ease[2]: DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04                                                                                                                                                                          │
│    /etc/*ease[3]: DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial                                                                                                                                                                        │
│    /etc/*ease[4]: DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"                                                                                                                                                       │
│    lsb_release: Distributor ID:        Ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                    │
│    lsb_release: Description:   Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS                                                                                                                                                                │
│    lsb_release: Release:       16.04                                                                                                                                                                             │
│    lsb_release: Codename:      xenial     



top - 01:40:58 up 13:13,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.20, 0.31
Tasks: 291 total,   1 running, 290 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.5 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.1 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 64020736 total, 59625188 free,  1529832 used,  2865716 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 65121788 total, 65121788 free,        0 used. 61697004 avail Mem
```

Comment: I would start by using `dmesg` to see messages that might offer a clue as to what's causing the hang.